# Authintication Error in Ionic WooCommerce using Angular

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, cordova, ionic-framework, woocommerce

I am implementing Woo Commerce Rest API in my Angular/Ionic project on Cordova Platform. While I am making $http request to get product list or any other data, I am getting error Message. Here is my Service code:

```
angular.module('services.serverRepo', [])
.service("serverRepo", 
['$q','$http','errorHandler','$ionicLoading',function($q,$http,errorHandler,$ionicLoading){

var baseUrl="www.abc.com/wc-api/";
var self=this;
this.products=function(){
    var deff=$q.defer();
    $http({
        method:"GET",
        url:baseUrl+"v3/products",
        headers: {
                    "Content-Type":"application/JSON",
                    "oauth_consumer_key":"gjdfjkbgbdhh645h6bh456b45hbhbgdfhgbdfhgbdfhgbhgbdhfghhfhf",
                    "consumer_secret":"cs_97d74bbf5e9052ee053a05cbb1a53eec19c0847c"
                }
        }).then(function(objS){
            alert('Success :-    '+JSON.stringify(objS));
        },function(objE){
            alert('error:-    '+objE);
            errorHandler.serverErrorhandler(objE);
            deff.reject("server Error");
        });
        return deff.promise;
    };
}])
.service('errorHandler',['$q',function($q){
    this.serverErrorhandler=function(error){
        alert("ERROR ::"+JSON.stringify(error));
        console.log("ERROR ::"+JSON.stringify(error));
    };
 }
])
```

and in my controller.js file code is:

```
$scope.rentaldeptt = function(){
    //$ionicHistory.clearCache();
        serverRepo.products().then(function(objS){

                                   },function(err){
        });
}
```

I am calling `$scope.rentaldeptt` on a button click. In response I am getting error message

> {"data":{"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_authentication_error","message":"oauth_timestamp parameter is missing"}]},"status":404,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"www.abc.com/v3/products","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"params":{"oauth_consumer_key":"gjdfjkbgbdhh645h6bh456b45hbhbgdfhgbdfhgbdfhgbhgbdhfghhfhf","consumer_secret":"cs_97d74bbf5e9052ee053a05cbb1a53eec19c0847c"}},"statusText":"Not Found"}

Any Idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: are you got solution ?

Comment: No, Still I did not get answer for this question

Comment: thank you for your replay, I got solution

Comment: It would be great if you post over here..

Comment: please check the answer is this right

Answer (score -1):

Please try to following steps to resolve the isue,

Here, I have Created  the service in angularjs to handle the calling of woocommerce api with the oauth,

```
            angular.module('myapp.restservices', [])
            .service("serverRepo",['$q','$http','errorHandler','$ionicLoading',function($q,$http,errorHandler,$ionicLoading){
                var self=this;
                 //Request Url and method
                var request = {
                        url: 'http://www.example.com/wc-api/v3/products',
                        method: 'GET'
                };  
                //OAuth Protocol authentication parameters
                var oauth = new OAuth({
                        consumer: {
                            //Consumer Public Key
                            public: 'ck_50xxxx',
                            //Consumer Secrete Key
                            secret: 'cs_b4xxxx'
                        },
                        //oauth1.0a protocol signature method
                        signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1'
                });

                //Service Function to get products
                this.products=function(){
                     $ionicLoading.show({
                            template: '<ion-spinner class="light"></ion-spinner>'
                     });
                     //OAuth Parameters to call woocommerce api
                    var oauth_data = {
                        oauth_consumer_key: oauth.consumer.public,
                        oauth_nonce: oauth.getNonce(),
                        oauth_signature_method: oauth.signature_method,
                        oauth_timestamp: oauth.getTimeStamp()
                    };
                    //Oauth signature
                    oauth_data.oauth_signature = oauthSignature.generate(request.method,request.url,oauth_data,oauth.consumer.secret );
                    console.log("Params : "+ JSON.stringify(oauth_data));
                    var deff=$q.defer();
                    $http({
                        method:"GET",
                        url:request.url,
                        headers: {
                                    "Content-Type":"application/JSON",
                                },
                        params: oauth_data
                        }).then(function(objS){
                            $ionicLoading.hide();
                            alert('Success :-    '+JSON.stringify(objS));
                        },function(objE){
                            $ionicLoading.hide();
                            alert('error:-    '+JSON.stringify(objE));
                            errorHandler.serverErrorhandler(objE);
                            deff.reject("server Error");
                        });
                        return deff.promise;
                    };
                }])
                .service('errorHandler',['$q',function($q){
                    this.serverErrorhandler=function(error){
                        alert("ERROR ::"+JSON.stringify(error));
                        console.log("ERROR ::"+JSON.stringify(error));
                    };
                 }
            ])
```

Write controller to call the service function as like follows,

```
    angular.module(myapp.categorycontrollers, [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,woocommerce) {
            //Method to get all Products
              $scope.getAllProducts = function(){
                    woocommerce.products().then(function(objS){
                     },function(err){
                    });
              }
             //calling to function
              $scope.getAllProducts();
     }
```

Hopes this will help you !